# Она покинула дом, никак непобедимый / не победимый никакими врагами

Tags: орфография

Я знаю, что это – прилагательное, которое вроде-то без *не-* не употребляется; но мне кажется, что, возможно, здесь это скорее причастие, в связи с чем надо бы-то раздельно писать. Помогите, ПЖ, мне в этом таки, ребят, разобраться.

• Она покинула дом, никак **непобедимый/не победимый** никакими врагами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Вот что говорит Розенталь:

> Однако остается в силе правило раздельного написания частицы ***не*** с прилагательными, если в качестве пояснительных слов выступают конструкции с отрицанием *ни*, в частности местоимения и наречия, начинающиеся с ***ни***, либо слова ***далеко, вовсе*** или ***отнюдь***: ***ни с чем не сравнимое** впечатление; **ни от кого не зависимые** страны; **отнюдь не растворимые** кристаллы; это явление **ни** из жизни, **ни** из искусства **не устранимо.***
> Исключение составляют слова, которые без ***не*** не употребляются: ***никем непобедимая** армия; **ни** для кого **непостижимый** случай; **ни** при каких условиях **неповторимый** эксперимент.*

**2.** Вот что говорит "Грамота" ([Вопрос № 214867; Вопрос № 213355](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BC&start=15)):
"никем НЕПОБЕДИМЫЙ воин" — следует писать слитно;
"никем непобедимая" — приведенное написание правильно.

И вот они, слова из песни (В. Лебедев-Кумач. Москва майская):
*Кипучая,

Могучая,

**Никем непобедимая**,

Страна моя,

Москва моя, —

Ты самая любимая!*

**3.** Так что правильно писать слитно.
*Она покинула дом, **никак непобедимый.**

Она покинула дом, **непобедимый никакими** врагами.*

**4.** В ранних текстах иногда встречается раздельное написание (на сегодня его нужно считать ошибочным):

*А то на скачки: женщина-жокей, первая в мире и **никем не победимая*** (А. И. Куприн. Юнкера (**1932**));
*Странная, **ничем не победимая** брезгливость, молодая, здоровая, жадная, как зеленая после дождя трава, выросла вдруг в Бабаеве* (С. Н. Сергеев-Ценский. Бабаев (**1906–1907**));
*Теперь он страшен, очень страшен, этот **никем не победимый** и побежденный Козакевичем богатырь, но ему не вырваться* (В. П. Беляев. Старая крепость (**1937–1940**)).

[Частица ***не*** с прилагательными](http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2257)

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: *Она покинула дом, никак непобедимый/непобедимый никакими врагами.*

1. **Это прилагательное,** НЕ пишется слитно.

**Вопрос № 239929**
Ответьте, пожалуйста, слитно или раздельно пишется слово непобедимы в данном предложении: *Вместе мы **непобедимы**.*

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Правильно слитное написание, т. к. в русском языке нет слова *победимы.

2. **И теория** [http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=победим](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC)

Пункт 3. Поскольку страдательные причастия настоящего времени могут быть только у переходных глаголов несов. вида, слова с суффиксами -им-, -ем- являются **прилагательными,** если они образованы от глагола **сов. вида** или непереходного глагола:

непромокаемые сапоги (прилагательное, т. к. глагол промокать в значении ‘пропускать воду’ непереходный),

непобедимая армия (прилагательное, т. к. глагол победить **сов. вида**).

3. Усиление отрицания и зависимое слово в Т.п. ничего не меняет: ***непобедимый** никем, никакими врагами.*

**НЕПОБЕДИМЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -дим, -а, -о. 1. Такой, которого трудно, невозможно победить. Н. полководец. Н-ая армия. Н-ое государство. Свободолюбивый народ непобедим. 2. Очень сильный, непреодолимый. Н. страх. Н-ое упрямство, любопытство. Н-ая уверенность. <Непобедимо, нареч. Н. сражаться. Непобедимость, -и; ж. Н. правды.

Answer (score 0):

> Она покинула дом, никак **непобедимый/не победимый** никакими врагами.

По-моему, неправильны оба варианта.

Победить можно воина, полководца, армию, страну…

**Но дом?..**

(Может, я и не прав.)

Answer (score 0):

Так не пишут, ввиду того, что "она покинула дом" - "дом" дополнение и существительное в русском языке. Чтобы сделать из слова дом понятие, нужно как минимум добавить "этот" или "тот", либо добавить прилагательное, либо еще как-то. Без всего этого во фразе "она покинула дом" слово дом будет реальным местом, домом - зданием, обычным дополнением, а не понятием дом. Поэтому это звучит неоднозначно и криво. Есть какой-то термин для обозначения таких моментов, по-английски называется типа "запутанный сад" если интересно, скину ссылку на вики, искать лень. То есть начало фразы звучит как обычное Они - кто-то, покинула - вышла, ушла, дом - ушла из дома-здания, а дальше идет предикативная конструкция, но к дополнению, и это разрушает конструкция восприятия предложения, получается дом не дом, а понятие дом, как можно уйти из понятия?

В общем придется делить предложение на две фразы:

**Она покинула его - дом непобедимый никакими врагами.**

В общем, даже просто прилагательного или тот/этот тут врад ли достаточно, потому что конструкция "непобедимый" бла-бла, вот такого страдательного вида может быть только к подлежащему, либо...

**Она покинула - дом непобедимый никакими врагами**, - может быть так можно.

Запятая тут лишняя, потому что тут дом - это не дополнение относящееся к глаголу, а целостное понятие, никаких страдательных залогов.

Ну и на счет раздельного слитного написания... Она покинула - дом, никем не побежденный. "Не победимый" к дому очень сомнительно, так как это мужской род, понятие и неодушевленный объект, был бы женский род, там может быть прокатило бы.